# c# string return with newline on webpage

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, newline

I have a c# string value returned from controller to the the webpage. The string has new lines but the webpage prints everything as one continuous line.

Here's my c#. I am trying various methods:

```
if (run5min)
                {
                    msg = db.FirstOrDefault<string>("SELECT Top 1 Timestamp_UTC FROM dbo.Admin_Log WHERE Details like 'Start%5min%' ORDER BY Timestamp_UTC DESC");                    
                    ret += String.Format("Started 5min Run {0} UTC | Count is: {1} \r\n\r\n", msg, count);
                }

                if (!runDay && !runHour && !run5min)
                {
                    var stop = db.FirstOrDefault<string>("SELECT Top 1 Timestamp_UTC FROM dbo.Admin_Log WHERE Details like 'Stop%' ORDER BY Timestamp_UTC DESC");

                    if (stop == null)
                    {
                        ret = "Nothing is running. \r\n\r\n";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ret = String.Format("Stopped at {0} UTC.<br/><br>", stop);
                    }                    
                }

                ret += "Day table count: " + countDay + "\n\n";
                ret += "Hour table count: " + countHour + "<br />";
                ret += "5min table count: " + count5min;
```

In the text visualizer in VS, it shows the newlines.

[image]

However, on the webpage, it prints all as one line that wraps to a second line.

Started 5min Run 9/9/2017 10:40:11 PM UTC | Count is: 0 /n/nDay table count: 0
Hour table count: 0 5min table count: 46132

Maybe I have the wrong dataType declared in the Ajax call?

```
$.ajax({
                url: "/Quote/Status",
                dataType: "text"
            }).done(function (response) {                                
                $("#message").text(response);
            })
```

How to fix?  Thanks!

Comment: Your element with `id="message"` should be styled with `style="white-space: pre;"` (or `pre-line`) - refer [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)

Comment: Also, using jQuery's `text()` function will strip any HTML you _do_ add, so use `html()` instead.

Comment: You can try to replace `\n` with `<br>` and use `.html()`

Comment: You are getting it wrapped to a second line because of the <br> FYI

Comment: S. Muecke's answer works if I use   \n\r   in the string returned from api. Thank you. I decided to go with using the other method:  using <br> in the string and $(#message).html(response). This works as well. Thanks to Tieson and LB !

Answer (score 0):

If your text has to be rendered in a browser try using

```
<br />
```

Instead of

```
\n
```

As HTML use the linebreak tag to break lines and not the usual "\n".